# A geometric question on angles and sides

Tags: geometry

I have problem solving this geometric question, notice that $ABCD$ is a diamond and $AE = AB$.

I wish to prove that $ED$ is an angle bisector of angle $E$.

[image]

Comment: Notice that ADBE is also a diamond. Diagonals of a parallelogram (diamond) bisect angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that AE = AB = AD. So, the triangle ADE is isosceles and $\angle$ADE = $\angle$AED.

Since AD || CE, we have $\angle$ADE = $\angle$DEB. Thus,

$$\angle AED = \angle DEB$$

Hence, DE is the angle bisector.